# How to List Custom Post Type Titles Based on Theirs Taxonomy Terms Inside a Nested Loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to list at least the last three updated Custom Post Type's title lets call it "Cast" inside another loop which is listed based on the Taxonomy terms called "Actress"
 I used the following loop to get the list of my tax terms:

```
$taxonomy = 'actress';
$term_args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . $tax_term->name.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
```

well this helped me to list the terms but I am really confused how to add the list of each terms associated custom post? to be more clear I illustrate following image,hopefully this will give you an idea what I am seeking for?
Can you please help me to figure out how to do this?
Thanks

**Update**

```
<?php
get_header();
$taxonomy = 'actress';
$term_args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $term) :

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            $term->slug
        )
    )
);

//  Now put the vars in the loop
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

// starting loop
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_title();
// do your thingie
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . $tax_term->name.'</li>';
}
endwhile;
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I am having a bit of a hard time understanding .. "cast" is CPT or taxonomy ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion Obmerk, the "cast" is CPT and the "actress" is the Custom Taxonamy

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed confusing - but mostlybecause I think you have used the CPT and taxonomies in a way which is not so semantic or correct ..

anyhow , try to put your loop INSIDE the foreach statement ..

```
foreach ($tax_term sas $term) :

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            $term->slug
        )
    )
);

//  Now put the vars in the loop
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

// starting loop
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_title();
// do your thingie

endwhile;

endforeach;
```

Now , I must say that it is not the best solution, and definitely not elegant - but it might just work for your case -- that is if I did not confuse myself with your terms and needs ..

Comment: Thanks Obmerk I tried to figure out how to use your code and ended up whith what have posted at update. but unfortunately it is is not displaying any of the list not the Custom Post Type neither Terms! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong again!